# difference between Jsp and JavaScript cookies

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies

What is the difference between a JavaScript cookie and a JSP set cookie?

When i set the cookie with JSP and retrieve it i receive everything as should.

However if i set the cookie with JavaScript and retrieve it with Jsp i only get the first word of a string. in this case the string is : " MB ASUS AMD AM3 M5A78L-M LX3"

JSP returns me : "MB "

Whereas JavaScript returns me the correct string.
My code:

Reading the cookie using **JSP**

```
<%
try{
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
boolean foundCookie = false;

for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) { 
    Cookie c = cookies[i];
    out.println( c.getName() + " = " + c.getValue());
    %><%=c.getValue() %>
    <br><%
    foundCookie = true;
} 
}catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
}
%>
```

Reading the cookie using **JavaScript**

```
<script>
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
var user=getCookie("moederboord");
alert("U have chosen " + user);</script>
```

Setting the cookie with **JSP**

```
<%String name = getspecs.gettitle(value);
Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("processor", name);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
response.addCookie(cookie);%>
```

Setting the cookie with **JavaScript**

```
<script>
function setCookie(){
    document.cookie="moederboord=<%=getspecs.gettitle(value)%>; path=/";
}

</script>
```

Comment: you need to show your JSP codes also

Comment: The code where i set the cookies? Code is added, pretty much all u need. Note that checking the cookie in Inspector does show me the correct value either way